# ImportError: No module named botocore.session

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I had already installed `boto3` but still it gives error of no module named botocore.session

```
import botocore.session
ImportError: No module named botocore.session
```

Comment: How did you install it? Did the installation actually succeed?

Comment: Yes @BaileyParker , Successfully installed version -> botocore<1.9.0,>=1.8.33->boto3 
Using -> pip install boto3

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#using-boto-3)

Comment: Thanks for sharing note @Phairero , I have gone through this document earlier, I am using boto3.client to connect with s3 bucket, for which further botocore.session is called , I am not sure why botocore.sesssion error is throwing irrespective of boto3 properly installed.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it with pip that is the same version of python that you are running?

Comment: Did you activate the correct virtual environment?

Comment: @LeoSkhrnkv , yes activated with correct virtual environment, well problem got solved with correct version install of boto3. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import boto3` alone is enough to connect with a bucket. `botocore.session` was used during for the previous boto 1.8 and is not accepted by boto3. you can refer the following boto3 documents  http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client . Here is boto 1.8 documents that mentions the use of botocore.session http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/

Comment: I guess you wanted to say that in boto3 a client object can be used instead of session: client_iam = client('iam'). 'import botocore.session' still works with boto3 though, I assume for backward compatibility. I am quite familiar with boto3 docs you mentioned, but I don't know where they say that botocore.session "is not accepted by boto3"

Answer (score 17):

I arrived here from Google. I was getting a similar error while updating AWS Lambda function code. The answer posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430022/278328) helped in my case. Simply upgrade AWS CLI. Hope this helps someone drifting here from search engines.

```
pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Answer (score 11):

I was on version `boto3-1.5.33` and `botocore-1.8.47` and upgrading to `boto3-1.9.75` and `botocore-1.12.75` solved the issue for me.

```
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

try `pip install boto3`. If not then try `pip install -U boto3`

Answer (score 1):

If you got conda environment also. Just use bellow command .

```
pip install --user awscli --upgrade
```

This works for me .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone attempting to install AWS CLI on Mac AND running Python 3.6, use pip3.6 instead of pip in your command-line.

Example:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
$ sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade awscli
...
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
...

## IF YOU GET THE ABOVE MESSAGE YOU CAN UPGRADE PIP USING
$ sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
```