# E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.compress'

Tags: python, pip, boto3, modulenotfounderror, botocore

I had both `boto3` and `botocore` installed in my conda venv, but was getting this error during compilation:

```bash
E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.compress'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107329/16852041) of the answer to a similar problem